# How to add all img in folder to CImage array element?

Tags: c++, bitmap, opendir, dirent.h

I have some trouble with that problem ;(
I don't know how to add img to CImage array element.
I want like these operation to do.↓

```
    image[0].Load(_T("./data/notice.bmp"));
    image[1].Load(_T("./data/11.bmp"));
    image[2].Load(_T("./data/22.bmp"));
    image[3].Load(_T("./data/13.bmp"));
    image[4].Load(_T("./data/25.bmp"));
    image[5].Load(_T("./data/7.bmp"));
    image[6].Load(_T("./data/16.bmp"));
    image[7].Load(_T("./data/20.bmp"));
    image[8].Load(_T("./data/18.bmp"));
    image[9].Load(_T("./data/3.bmp"));
    image[10].Load(_T("./data/8.bmp"));
```

I want to add bmp files to CImage array named image!
I think maybe there is some way to do this at once. :0
I found 'dirent.h' on Google. 
But I don't know how to use this correctly to do my work.. ;(

```
    DIR             *d;
    struct dirent   *dir;
    CImage image[MAX_IMAGE];
    d = opendir("./data/");
    int i=0;

    if(d)
    {
            while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
            {
                    i++;
                    image[i] = *dir->d_name;
            }
            closedir(d);
    }
```

There is occur some error

```
    image[i] = *dir->d_name;
```

How to get fix it? ;((

Answer (score 0):

`image` is an array of elements of type `CImage`, `dirent::d_name` is of type `char …[256]`.

Those two don't get together. I think you want to use something like

```
image[i].Load(dir->d_name);
```

but this is still rather bad style. You should use a `std::vector<CImage>` or a `std::list<CImage>` instead.